How can I accessthe "guid" of a google chrome bookmark?
I need to access the guid of a google chrome bookmark using the chrome.bookmarks API.
The guid is the only value I found that won't change across different computers when you sync the bookmarks in different computers.
I tried checking all the methods to access the guid of a bookmark but couldn't find any except directly accessing the "bookmarks" file.

The documentation lists all accessible properties. The closest is id.
